# Set Bar Button Items color in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

In my view controller I can set my bar button item like this

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But what I want to achieve is to set it in my app delegate so that all my bar button items on all view controllers are white something similar to doing this

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I can get it to work on text but I want to change it for images

Sample Image,

[image: Sample Image]

**Edited:**
How I set my image

[image]

Comment: Try this
`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal`

Comment: @New16 it works for the text but does not work on the images. Do you have a solution for setting the tint color on an image?

Comment: refer this article, https://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-bar-back-butto/ . IN this article they mentioned that how to change tint and customize navigation bar in app delegate. @Lian van der Vyver

Comment: Have you refer above url? @LianvanderVyver

Comment: @KAR thanks but this won't help in my scenario. That only works on back buttons. I have left and right sided buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same strategy to change the UINavigationBar barTintColor and titleTextAttributes:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // this will change the back button tint
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                               forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Edited:**

```
UIImage *selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: it works for the text but does not work on the images. Do you have a solution for setting the tint color on an image?

Comment: You want to change the UINavigationBar image color?

Comment: No my bar button item has an image and I want to set the color of that image. I can set it with this code [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; then it works but can't get a solution in my app delegate to work. I have provided and image in my question for you click on sample.

Comment: No the image is set. I just want to change its color from the app delegate.

Comment: But how you set that image? You just need to set that image like above.

Comment: Can you show me how you set the image in ViewController?

Comment: I've set my image in the storyboard. But we have 5 apps that uses the same code base but each client has different themes. So I need to change the color of that image based on each client. I can do it in the view controller but now I need to duplicate this codes in 30 different view controllers. So that is why I want a solution to do it in the app delegate. Hope this makes better sense.

Comment: See my question on how I set the image.

Comment: Yes I got your point but for that you need to set your image property "UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal". Doing this you can change the tint color of that image in AppDelegate.

Comment: Okay. Just Make that imageview property and add this code: **[self.imageView setImage:[self.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];**

Comment: Okay thanks I understand but not what I need. For now I will just set the color in each view controller.

Comment: This solution is what you want but don't know why you are facing problem.
But I tried to help you and its working also. So please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

// Make in Appdelegate.h

```
@property(nonatomic)UIColor* appDelColor;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

// set AppDelegate Color

```
appDelegate.appDelColor= [UIColor redColor];
```

//get AppDelegate Color

```
UIColor *appDELColor=appDelegate.appDelColor;
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to set my bar button items color in the app delegate and not the color in an app delegate.

Comment: ok then you can make @propery in appdelegate.h and assign it in appdelegate.m , then you can use it where you want

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return YES;
}
```

May this will help you.. :)